# Capturing WSO2 DSS Service Errors in WSO2 ESB Proxy Service

Tags: wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

Good Day!

I have a WSO2 ESB proxy service which is calling WSO2 DSS Service. It is inserting the data to mysql table. it is working as expected. but if there is any issue in the DSS Service, I am getting faults with different soap response formats. like

if the service is inactive or stopped, then getting response like

```
<soapenv:Body><soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">.......
```

if the service is facing issue while inserting the data, then getting response like

```
<soapenv:Body><axis2ns134:DataServiceFault xmlns:axis2ns134="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"><axis2ns134:current_params......
```

and some other cases getting different responses.

but is ESB, those errors are not capturing and not firing "faultsequence" even I explicitly set the below property

```
<property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"                 scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Can you please guide me how to handle/catch those errors in ESB Proxy?

Thanks,

Vinoth

Comment: can you share the proxy config?

Answer (score 0):

see if this documentation helps you.

https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Fault+Mediator
https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Error+Handling

Att;

Vitor Darela

Comment: Hi, I explicitly handled the different types of fault error response which is coming from DSS Service. I Mean once the response is received from DSS, I am verifying the response and if it is fault, then create a fault response which is expected by ESB and throw it by using FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT property.